# Jmeter Regular Expression Extraction

Tags: regex, jmeter

Could someone help me in getting the value "1237857346" from the following using regex or any other way I could get the value "1237857346" in from HTML in JMeter.

```html
<select class="card_account" name="existing__account">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled">Card Number</option>
  <option value="1237857346" selected="selected">************4567</option>
</select>
```

Little bit of background. I am using JMeter and trying to extra the value "1237857346" to pass it in the next request.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very good idea to parse HTML using Regular Expressions as it evidenced by the [famous Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748)

I would suggest switching to [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead. Add the XPath Extractor as a child of HTTP Request sampler which returns that select and configure it as follows:

- XML Parsing Options: tick `Use Tidy` box. It may not be necessary but if your server response is not XML/XHTML compliant you'll get nothing
- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `value` - it will be the name of the variable holding extracted data
- XPath Expression: `//select[@class='card_account']/option[@selected='selected']/@value` - it will take

  - select having class = card_account
  - option with selected = "selected"
  - value attribute of the above option

and store it to "value" variable. You will be able to refer to it as `${value}` where required.

See following material for further reference:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)
- [XPath Language Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I know about XPATH as I work alot on then day to day. Your suggestion is working like a champ... Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
<option[^<]*>Card Number</option>\s*<option[^<]*?value="(\d+)"
```

The value will be in group 1 ($1$), which is exactly what you need.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Coption%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3ECard%20Number%3C%2Foption%3E%5Cs*%3Coption%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3Fvalue%3D%22(%5Cd%2B)%22&i=%3Cselect%20class%3D%22card_account%22%20name%3D%22existing__account%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Coption%20value%3D%22%22%20disabled%3D%22disabled%22%3ECard%20Number%3C%2Foption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Coption%20value%3D%221237857346%22%20selected%3D%22selected%22%3E************4567%3C%2Foption%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fselect%3E)

In case the are always *12 asterisks* (that can be matched with `\*{12}`) in the `<option>` node value, you'd can use:

```
<option[^<]*value="(\d+)"[^<]*>\*{12}\d+</option>
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Coption%5B%5E%3C%5D*value%3D%22(%5Cd%2B)%22%5B%5E%3C%5D*%3E%5C*%7B12%7D%5Cd%2B%3C%2Foption%3E&i=%3Cselect%20class%3D%22card_account%22%20name%3D%22existing__account%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Coption%20value%3D%22%22%20disabled%3D%22disabled%22%3ECard%20Number%3C%2Foption%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Coption%20value%3D%221237857346%22%20selected%3D%22selected%22%3E************4567%3C%2Foption%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fselect%3E).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used the xpath and its working. I would you regex suggestion for future. :)

Comment: Sure, you can use my suggestion as a fallback.